# How to create table of contents from HTML table

Tags: html

I am trying to create a table of contents from a html (snippet attached) file that has a massive table.

Essentially i want to create a hyperlinked table of contents which references the first and second columns of the table as follows:

```
Table of Contents:

main 1
  one
  two
main 2
  one
  two
```

```html
<pre><table border="1"><tr><th>main 1</th><td><table border="1"><tr><th>one</th><td><br><pre>blah blah blah<br></td></tr></pre><tr><th>two</th><td><br><pre>blah blah<br></td></tr></pre></table></td></tr><tr><th>main 2</th><td><table border="1"><tr><th>one</th><td><br>blah blah blah<br></td></tr><tr><th>two</th><td><br>blah blah blah<br></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></pre>
```

So when we click on `main1` in the table of contents it should take us to the main1 section of the table and so on

EDIT: the table of content needs to be added to the same html file (as attached in the snippet) at the top

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Please clear your question as it's not at all clear. Code is fine and creating a table, so where is the issue?

Comment: Your HTML is totally invalid. Fix that first.

Comment: Isn't a nested list a better option when trying to achieve a standard table of contents?

Comment: @BertijnPauwels The table is what the toc refers to and must be created from, not the toc itself.

Comment: So to recall for future readers: The person has a html snippet as seen in OP. He tries to create a table of contents, based on that html file. I assume he wants to use Javascript for this? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: do we have to use JS. Can this be achieved using plain `html`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the errors in your table code - you can get a list of th elements via querySelectorAll. I do not love the nested tables, but I tried to stay true to the code you had started with.

```js
var contents = document.querySelectorAll('table th');

var contentStr ='';

contents.forEach(function(content){
  contentStr += '<li>'+ content.innerHTML + '</li>';
 })

document.getElementById('contents-list').innerHTML = contentStr;
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>main 1</th>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>one</th>
          <td>blah blah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>two</th>
          <td>blah blah</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>main 2</th>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>one</th>
          <td>blah blah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>two</th>
          <td>blah blah blah</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr/>
<ul id ="contents-list"></ul>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. However, I am after a hyperlinked table of contents to be added on the top of this html file. So that you can click on `main 1` and it sould take you to main 1 section of the table

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Main 1</th>
    <th colspan="2">Main 2</th>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>

    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blah blah</td>
    <td>Blah blah</td>

    <td>Blah blah</td>
    <td>Blah blah</td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (more info [here](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/create-auto-generated-table-of-contents-html-slot/)):

```js
    templateContent = document.querySelector('template').content;
    article = document.querySelector('article').cloneNode(true);
    article.querySelectorAll('*[id]').forEach((ele)=>{ele.removeAttribute('id')})
    article.attachShadow({  mode: 'closed' }).appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
    document.querySelector('#toc').appendChild(article);
```

```css
article {
  counter-reset: heading;
}
article h2::before {
  counter-increment: heading;
  content: '0'counter(heading)': ';
}
```

```html
      <template>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href='#h-1'><slot name='h-1'></slot></a>
            <ul>
              <li><slot name='sh-1-1'></slot></li>
              <li><slot name='sh-1-2'></slot></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#h-2'><slot name='h-2'></slot></a>
            <ul>
                <li><slot name='sh-2-1'></slot></li>
                <li><slot name='sh-2-2'></slot></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <style>
          ul {
            list-style: none;
          }
        </style>
        </template>

        <div id='toc'></div>


        <article>
          <h2 id='h-1' slot='h-1'>Main 1</h2>
          <p>Main 1 Description...</p>
          
            <h3 slot='sh-1-1'>One</h3>
            <p>Blah blah blah</p >

            <h3 slot='sh-1-2'>Two</h3>
            <p>Blah blah</p >
          
          <h2 id='h-2' slot='h-2'>Main 2</h2>
          <p>Main 2 Description...</p>

            <h3 slot='sh-2-1'>One</h3>
            <p>Blah blah blah</p >

            <h3 slot='sh-2-2'>Two</h3>
            <p>Blah blah</p >
        </article>
```